# Compute pairwise distances between two layers

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, rgeo

In R, I have polygon layer A and point layer B. Both have the same number of features, there is one-to-one correspondence (pairing): each polygon of the layer A has a corresponding point in layer B and vice versa.
**How do I compute pairwise distances between these pairs of features?**

I tried to use

```
gDistance(A, B, byid = TRUE)
```

but this will compute the whole N<sup>2</sup> matrix, which is huge overhead (I would only use the diagonal of that matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, seems rgeos and `gDistance` can't do it... So I found solution using the `sf` library:

```
require(sf)
g1 <- st_as_sf(A)
g2 <- st_as_sf(B)
dist <- st_distance(g1, g2, by_element=TRUE)
```

This is going to generate pairwise distances.